# Syntax error or access violation when query returns empty

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am getting some weird error if the query returns nothing.  How can I handle this properly?

Error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1 (SQL: select `users`.`uid`, `first_name`, `last_name`, IFNULL(files.filename, 'default.jpg') AS avatar, `privacy` from `users` left join `user_avatars` on `users`.`uid` = `user_avatars`.`uid` left join `files` on `user_avatars`.`fid` = `files`.`fid` where `users`.`uid` in ())

Code:

```
$me = User::loggedin();
$contacts = DB::table('contacts')
        ->where('status', 'contact')
        ->where('uid_by', $me)
        ->orWhere('uid_to', $me)
        ->select(
        DB::raw("IF(uid_by = $me, uid_to, uid_by) AS user_id")
        )
            ->paginate(10);

if ($contacts != null) {
    $users_id = array();

    foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
    $users_id[] = $contact->user_id;
}

$data = DB::table('users')
        ->leftJoin('user_avatars', 'users.uid', '=', 'user_avatars.uid')
        ->leftJoin('files', 'user_avatars.fid', '=', 'files.fid')
        ->whereIn('users.uid', $users_id)
            ->select('users.uid', 'first_name', 'last_name', DB::raw('IFNULL(files.filename, \'default.jpg\') AS avatar'), 'privacy')
            ->get();


return Response::json(array('contacts' => $data));          
}

//if no data was returned
return Response::json(array('contacts' => 0));
```

---

**update**

I tried adding `die(var_dump($contacts));` but it returning alot of laravel related objects.

On another note if I add ?page=1 then it returns 2 contacts SUCCESSFULLY.
If I add ?page=2 then it gives the error. (probably because there is no data) but I want to handle this properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put some logic around the line

```
>whereIn('users.uid', $users_id)
```

since you've chained the calls, you can't simply put an if around that line (not that it'd work logically anyway. perhaps this would do it..

```
if ($users_id){
$data = DB::table('users')
                            ->leftJoin('user_avatars', 'users.uid', '=', 'user_avatars.uid')
                            ->leftJoin('files', 'user_avatars.fid', '=', 'files.fid')
                            ->whereIn('users.uid', $users_id)
                            ->select('users.uid', 'first_name', 'last_name', DB::raw('IFNULL(files.filename, \'default.jpg\') AS avatar'), 'privacy')
                            ->get();
} else {$data = null; /*or empty set however that is defined in your framework*/ }
```

Comment: What I did was I edited `$users_id = array();` to `$users_id = array(0);` now it deosn't give the error. But my question now is, is there a better or more efficient way in handling this?

Comment: Yes, the framework SHOULD be able to handle that in some kind of way, but honestly, I think your "fix" could not be a fix at all if there is a users.uid=0 row.. there might not be, but it's a risk you run with the code you wrote. You really don't need the conditional on an empty array-- either you need to return no rows automatically (not even run the query), or you need to ignore the condition as it's going to always create this syntax error in the sql.

Comment: Did you try my code though? It would be more efficient as well, not lagging your db server with an unnecessary query.

Comment: So you suggest that I just check if users_id contains anything and if it does then run my query? if not then don't run the query at all?

Comment: Yes, I did try your code. It works. Will accept this answer. :)

Comment: Thanks. and yes, I suggest not running the query at all if the $users_id is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ($contacts != null) {
    $users_id = array();

    foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
        $users_id[] = $contact->user_id;
    }
```

That part of your code is not working right. do a var_dump($contacts); and see what it really is, because it must not be null, it looks like it's just an empty array.

Comment: I added `die(var_dump($contacts));` and it seems to be returning a very long object containing alot of laravel stuff. hmmmm.

Comment: To elaborate, what happens is that it produces the SQL `...users.uid in ()`, which is a syntax error. You can't have an empty list.

Comment: Okay, What object type / class name was at the top of that list? :)

Comment: I changed the var to `$users_id = array(0);` now if gives a 0 in the list as default. But is there a better solution to this? or is the one I'm using OK? I'm expecting a traffic of millions of user.

Comment: You could add a simple count() to the $users_id array, only run the second query if the $users_id has at least one value.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you cannot pass an empty data set with `IN`. For example, `SELECT id FROM users WHERE id IN ()` is not valid SQL. Laravel is not savvy enough to correct the issue; so you'll need to make an adjustment. A quick fix is to append a non-member like `0` to the data set. (In this case, it's probably safe to assume to no data has a primary key of `0`.)

For example, in your code:

```
$users_id = array(0);

foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
    $users_id[] = $contact->user_id;
}
```